# Stick with TortoiseSVN 1.6?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

In the team everybody still works with the client TortoiseSVN 1.6. I tried out 1.7 and I find it a big improvement on a Windows 7 machine.
My team members tell me we can't upgrade. But they can't tell me the exact reason?! It was told by somebody a while ago but that somebody left the company :)

Is there a valid reason to stick with 1.6?

**Edit**

Beside the changed working copy format, is the benefit of 1.7 higher then the cost of upgrading of 1.6.

Answer (score 4):

The [working copy format has changed](http://tortoisesvn.net/tsvn_1.7_releasenotes.html) in 1.7.

You'd have to upgrade all clients that use the same working copy to 1.7 at once: older clients will no longer be able to access the WC once it has been upgraded.

There *may* be reasons speaking against doing that under certain circumstances (like if [non-Tortoise] clients don't have the upgraded svn client libraries built in yet). You'd have to look at the clients that are being used.

I have upgraded several TortoiseSVN-only work enviroments over the past couple months and have had no problems. (Of course, it is wise to check in all changes prior to upgrading, just in case.)

Comment: VisualSVN is one of these client I guess?

Comment: @Nick no, VisualSVN is a Windows SVN server. It should not be affected by changes to the working copy.

Comment: I mean the [client](http://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/) version, which integrates in MS Visual Studio.

Comment: @Nick ahh, right. Forgot about that one, sorry. [It seems to be supporting Subversion 1.7 since last october](http://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/changes/)

Comment: The phrase "all clients" is a bit misleading in the answer.  Some users can remain on 1.6 while you upgrade to 1.7.  The working copy change only matters if you have multiple people touching the same working copy (e.g. a checked out copy shared on a network drive).